# Leveraging resource system with WebView and "file:///android_res/" for .css files

Tags: android, css, webview, android-resources

I am trying to do a reading type application, where I am downloading html-formatted articles and displaying them in a `WebView` and styling them with local .css from assets.

I load it all with `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

However, the problem is that .css uses `px` as a unit, so I guess this wont fly, and I want to adjust the values for using on tablets and different orientations as you would normally do. Then I heard, that WebView is able to load stuff from resources with `"file:///android_res/"` as base url.

So I was wondering, I could use this to my .css file in `/raw` folder, and leverage the resource system with qualifiers `/raw-land`, `/raw-sw720` etc., like you normally would when styling layouts.

Unfortunatelly, this doesnt seem to work, even if I do something like `"file:///android_res/raw/land/"` but hardcoding the path kinda defeats the purpouse anyways.

So .. is there any solution to this? My biggest worry is using pixels as units, but webview seems to adjust stuff on its own, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned you can use conditional stylesheet tags within the CSS file, which Android will understand.

More information regarding this can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

For example, you can create separate stylesheets for each density:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" href="hdpi.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.0)" href="mdpi.css" />
```